# using content of a pandas row to create another pandas row (help me optimize this really ugly function)

Tags: python, pandas

```
short['SOURCE'] = None
for x in range(len(short)):
    if (short['AMOUNT'].iloc[x] > 0) & (len(short['ACCOUNT'].iloc[x]) >1):
        short['SOURCE'].iloc[x] = short['ACCOUNT'].iloc[x][1]
    elif short['AMOUNT'].iloc[x] > 0:
        short['SOURCE'].iloc[x] = "Guy"
    else:
        short['SOURCE'].iloc[x] = short['MERCHANT'].iloc[x]
```

the goal:

Look at columns ACCOUNT and SOURCE.

If ACCOUNT has 2 strings and source is positive, set SOURCE to the second string

if ACCOUNT has 1 string, set SOURCE to that string

If AMOUNT is negative, set SOURCE to column MERCHANT.

This is a super ugly, super hacky, super slow solution. Is there a better one?

Comment: I better way to "optimise" would be to see your current dataframe and expected output. Quite often the "optimisation" involves re-writing your code with a different approach.

Comment: If my data frame has 3 columns MERCHANT, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT and I want to create the 4th column called SOURCE that is filtered by the rules I outlined: if the account has two strings in it, use the second string for source. if amount is negative, use merchant for source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), for length of strings [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
short = pd.DataFrame({'AMOUNT':[0,0,5,8],
                      'ACCOUNT':['a','a s','d f','f'],
                      'MERCHANT':list('abcd')})

m1 = short['AMOUNT'] > 0
m2 = m1 & (short['ACCOUNT'].str.len() > 1)

short['SOURCE'] = np.select([m2, m1], [short['ACCOUNT'], 'Guy'], default = short['MERCHANT'])
print (short)
  ACCOUNT  AMOUNT MERCHANT SOURCE
0       a       0        a      a
1     a s       0        b      b
2     d f       5        c    d f
3       f       8        d    Guy
```